# Error: unknown flag `p' when trying to run ionic cordova run android

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an ionic cordova project in which i tried to run with ionic cordova run android (sometimes with sudo too) and it returns me this error: `error: unknown flag p'` and `/usr/bin/snap: Command failed with exit code 64`.

I have tried reinstalling node, npm, ionic and cordova but it hasn't worked out for me :/
I also have removed platforms, removed plugins, node_modules but no luck also.

When i do a ionic cordova prepare android, the script runs perfectly but i get this error when i try to run or emulate it

My node version is v10.24.0, npm version 6.14.11, ionic 5.4.12 and cordova 10.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finnaly solved it by uninstalling gradle and then installing it again on version 5.6.3

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had initially installed gradle using the snap(snapcraft) repository and the gradle version mentioned in

> platforms/android/cdv-gradle-config.json

didn't match.

**Solution**

**I uninstalled the gradle which i had installed from snap and installed the version of gradle mentioned in my ionic project**